# Error Creating Registry Key for appName = <>

Tags: c#, xml, quickbooks

Trying to connect to a Quickbooks instance, using QB Web Connector 2.2.

This is to Premier Professional Services Edition 2015.

Here's my log:

```
20170501.19:27:08 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>QBDrupal</AppName>
  <AppID />
  <AppURL>https://localhost3.dd:8443/qb-soap/</AppURL>
  <AppDescription>Test for Drupal</AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>https://localhost3.dd:8443/qb-soap/</AppSupport>
  <UserName>Admin</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-967DE1813D20}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Style>Document</Style>
  <AuthFlags>0xF</AuthFlags>
</QBWCXML>
20170501.19:27:08 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
20170501.19:27:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>
20170501.19:27:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
20170501.19:27:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving QBDrupal to Registry: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
20170501.19:27:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20170501.19:28:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <Could not start QuickBooks.>.
20170501.19:28:24 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.
<Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <Could not start QuickBooks.>.>
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.AddToQuickBooks()
20170501.19:28:26 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : QBWC1015: Error closing connection to QuickBooks.
Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
```

I am getting alert messages popping up like this:

(this one is immediately after loading the QWC file)

```
QuickBooks already has a company file open (**NOTE: IT DOESN'T**). If you want to open another company file, close this one first.

Only QuickBooks Accountant and QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions can open two company files at once.
```

And this one happens about a minute or so after:

```
QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.

Error connecting to Quickbooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <Could not start QuickBooks.>.

If you do not have QuickBooks installed on this system, you would need to install it before running web connector
```

Not quite sure why it's erroring out. Any enlightenment?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this issue: you should ensure that QuickBooks is running BEFORE you open the qwc file. Once I did that (using web connection 2.2.0.71 and QuickBooks Premier 2017) I was able to successfully get past this.